# Why is loop not stopping using 'continue'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, continue

So I am new at programming and I was writing some practice code (Python 3.6):

```
while True:
    print('Hello Steve, what is the password?')
    password = input()
    if password != '1234':
        continue
    print('Access granted')
```

The problem i'm having is that even though I am typing the correct password, the loop continues.Can you help me figure out what I did wrong?

Comment: use `break` instead of `continue`

Comment: Or to expand on that, the while True loop can only be exited with a break statement

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? The code is not very clear about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`continue` will skip *the rest of the current round* in the loop, and then the loop will start over:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> while i < 5:
...     i += 1
...     if i == 3:
...         continue
...     print(i)
...
1
2
4
5
>>>
```

What you're looking for is the `break` keyword, which will exit the loop completely:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> while i < 5:
...     i += 1
...     if i == 3:
...         break
...     print(i)
...
1
2
>>>
```

However, notice that `break` will jump out of the loop completely, and your `print('Access granted')` is *after* that. So what you want is something like this:

```
while True:
    print('Hello Steve, what is the password?')
    password = input()
    if password == '1234':
        print('Access granted')
        break
```

Or use the `while` loop's condition, although this requires repeating the `password = ...`:

```
password = input('Hello Steve, what is the password?\n')
while password != '1234':
    password = input('Hello Steve, what is the password?\n')
print('Access granted')
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response!

Comment: Last ones gives `NameError: name 'password' is not defined`.

Comment: And now the user must input something but isn't told that they must do so.

Comment: @StefanPochmann oh master, show me how to `do`/`while` in Python. Like I already mentioned, "*although this requires repeating the `password = ...`*". There's no perfect `do`/`while` in Python, you either `while True:` (which I've shown) or repeat the input (which I've shown). If you have a better method, feel free to enlighten us ;)

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Simply initialize with `password = None` instead.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well yeah, it'll still be repeating the `pasword = ...`, just with `None` instead of `input(...)`. I guess it's a bit cleaner, but there isn't a perfect solution in Python since we're not allowed `do`/`while`

Answer (score 0):

Change `break` instead of `continue`, should work.

Comment: So, there is no way to do this with continue?Sorry for the stupid questions i'm quite new at this.

Comment: use break, it is provided for that reasn only to stop the loop, it is opposite of continue

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're using the wrong logical operator for equality comparison, this: `!=` is for **not equals**; and this `==` is for **equals**.

Second, as other have already stated, you should use `break` instead of `continue`.

I would do something like this:

```
print('Hello Steve!')
while True:
    password = input('Type your password: ')
    if password == '1234':
        print('Access granted')
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong password, try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using break statement instead of continue.
Your code should look like this

```
while True:
    print('Hello Steve, what is the password?')
    password = input()
    if password == '1234':
        print('Access granted')
        break
```